# I want to count number of occurance of specific group in Generic List

Tags: c#, linq

I have two class .

```
public  class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have data for above class , please check below .

```
  List<Employee> lstEmployee = new List<Employee>();
  lstEmployee.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = "Ronak", LastName = "Patel" });
  lstEmployee.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = "Ronak", LastName = "Patel" });
  lstEmployee.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = "Sanjay", LastName = "Patel" });
  lstEmployee.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = "Ronak", LastName = "Patel" });
  lstEmployee.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = "Sanjay", LastName = "Patel" });
  lstEmployee.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = "Ronak", LastName = "Patel" });
  lstEmployee.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = "Mohan", LastName = "Patel" });
```

I want filter above generic list and bound into below structure class .

```
class CountEmployeeName
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int CountFirstName { get; set; }
}
```

I want bind CountEmployeeName class object as per above data like below sample .

```
FirstName    CountFirstName 
Ronak              4         (Ronak is 4 time in above Employee class list)
Sanjay             2         (Sanjay is 4 time in above Employee class list)
Mohan              1         (Mohan is 4 time in above Employee class list)
```

I want to bind Generic List of CountEmployeeName class like above output as per given data for Employee List .

Comment: Have you tried solving this independently?

Comment: Why are you using a string to store counts? Have you tried something? Did you encounter some problem? Or are you asking in general how to calculate groups?

Comment: Since you already tagged this `LINQ`, you should google for `LINQ GROUP COUNT`. The very first result is a highly-upvoted duplicate

Comment: Duplicate questions add noise that make it harder for the next person to find a good answer. That's why they are discouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use linq `group by` and then in the `select` project to your second type:

```
from item in lstEmployee
group item by item.FirstName into grouping
select new CountEmployeeName
{
    FirstName = grouping.Key,
    CountFirstName = grouping.Count()
}
```

In method syntax it will look like this:

```
lstEmployee.GroupBy(item => item.FirstName)
                   .Select(grouping => new CountEmployeeName { 
                       FirstName = grouping.Key, 
                       CountFirstName = grouping.Count() 
                   });
```

*Note that I'd recommend changing the `CountFirstName` to an `int` rather than `string`*

Comment: Seems here `CountFirstName = grouping.Count()` need to add `ToString()` at the end, right?

Comment: @MegaTron a better option would be to change the field to an integer, and leave formatting to the presentation layer, eg the MVC View

Comment: yes @PanagiotisKanavos, I agree but it was just a small remark to make these code working on OP source

Comment: @MegaTron - you are correct and ill add a comment but it is better not to convert it to a string

Comment: @MegaTron the OP should have googled before adding *another* question about grouping, making it harder for the next guy to find an answer. Using the wrong type for a field is an annoying bug - typically the next question is "Why doesn't my number appear the way I want it to?"

Comment: @RonakPatel - Did this help you understand how to do it?

Comment: Yes.got it..thanks everyone .

Comment: I already did it .

Comment: @RonakPatel - strange.. it should have a green V just under the score of the answer..

Comment: @Green. Lets enjoy .

Comment: @RonakPatel - cool thanks :)