# using group by in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a problem in group by with link to sql
first I have this tables :

1. **client** : Id_client , nom , prenom , villeId
2. **ville**: id_ville , nom

Code:

```
 justiceDataContext dbContext = new justiceDataContext();
        GridView1.DataSource = from client in dbContext.Client
                               join ville in dbContext.Commande
                               on client.villeId equals ville.Id_ville
                               group client by ville.nom into g
                               select new { City = g.Key, NumberOfClients = g.Count() };
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

My objective is to get number of  `client` by city (`ville`)

thank you

Comment: you want to count how many clients in each city, or you want to show the city id next to the client? It's a little unclear what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to count number of occurance of specific group in Generic List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526771/i-want-to-count-number-of-occurance-of-specific-group-in-generic-list)

Comment: should be something along `select new { ville.nom, s.Distinct().Count() } `

Comment: @Nadine please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dbContext.Client
    .GroupBy(c => c.villeId)
    .Select(g => new {
        CityName = dbContext.Villes.Where(v => v.Id_ville == g.Key),
        NumberOfClient = g.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

---

Another approach:

```
var result = dbContext.Villes
            .Join(dbContextClients, v => v.IdVille, c => c.IdVille, (v, c)  => new { client = c, ville = v })
            .GroupBy(j => j.ville.IdVille)
            .Select(g => new {
                VilleName = g.First().ville.Name,
                NumberOfClients = g.Count()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks soooo much it works to me :)  thanks a loooot